# Retrieving the start and end character indices in the original document, for those sentences returned by Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am using something similar to the following pattern to retrieve the start and end indices of Spacy's sentences in the original document:

```
nlp = spacy.en.English()
doc = nlp(fulltext)

tot = 0
prev_end=0
for sent in doc.sents:
    x = re.search(re.escape(sent.text), fulltext)
    print (x.start(), x.end(), ">>>", sent.text)
    tot += (x.end()-prev_end)
    prev_end = x.end()

if len(fulltext) == tot: print ("works")
```

This seems to work for those few test docs I used. But worried if I am overlooking any 'gotchas' like spacy sometimes stripping off some characters that I am not aware of . Am I?

PS: If it helps, I need these indices to compare with indices I have from Brat's annotation file.

Comment: I am not aware of the caveats you mention, but I just wonder why you are using a regex to get the literal  substring position: you may use a mere `find()` / `index()`. Besides, when you run `re.search`, you should check if there was a match before accessing the `.start()` and `end()`.

Comment: Thanks, that is reassuring. I will check out find/index, but since I use regex heavily in other parts of the code, it is more of a habit I guess. And ya, I did have `if x is not None` but took it off here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `sent.start_char` and `sent.end_char` attributes. These give exactly the indices you're after: https://spacy.io/docs/api/span#attributes

Also `doc.text` should **always** equal the original full text. If it doesn't, please submit a bug report.